# Attractive central force problem with impact parameter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics, gravity

Let $m$ be a mass subjected to a central force:

$$\vec{F}(r) = -\frac{k \mu}{r^3} \vec{u_r} $$

Where $k$ is a positive constant and $\mu$ is the reduced mass of the system with the centre of forces situated at the origin of coordinates $O$. Its orbit equation in terms of the angle $\phi$ is ($u = 1/r$):

$$u''(\phi) + u(\phi)(1-\frac{k\mu^2}{l^2}) = 0$$

Where $l$ is the angular momentum. Then I have to solve this equation for a specific case where the initial conditions are the following: the particle is at an infinite distance from the origin of the center of force $O$, it moves anti-parallel to the axis $X$ with impact parameter $d$ with respect to $O$, and the modulus of its velocity is $v$ (see figure).

[image]

**Attempt**: I have solved the differential equation for two cases:

1. The term $1-\frac{k\mu^2}{l^2}$ is positive, so $k < l^2/\mu^2$ and the general solution is:

$$u(\phi) = A\sin({\sqrt{1-\frac{k\mu^2}{l^2}}\phi + \delta})$$

Does this mean the particle will do an SHM in one dimension passing through the centre of force?

2. The term $1-\frac{k\mu^2}{l^2}$ is negative, so $k > l^2/\mu^2$ and the general solution is:

$$u(\phi) = Ae^{\sqrt{1-\frac{k\mu^2}{l^2}}\phi} + Be^{-\sqrt{1-\frac{k\mu^2}{l^2}}\phi}$$

Where depending on the $A$ and $B$ values, the movement will spiral around the centre (bounded) (1) or from the centre to infinity (unbounded) (2).

However, I cannot identify which one of these cases fit with the problem. I guess is the first one of the second case, but I'm not pretty sure, because I haven't done any exercise about attractive forces with an impact parameter. Could anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure we can argue for #1 or #2 given the information you (or the problem) has the provided. If you don't have any additional constraints on the angular momentum, you can't say whether the projectile will be bounded or unbounded to the center of potential. As in your 2nd equation, the relative values of $l^2$ and $k\mu^2$ is what matters.

Comment: In this problem angular momentum $l$ would be (because of initial conditions): $l = mvd$, because we can make the approach $\mu = m$ .

Comment: Correct, this means the term in your problem becomes $\frac{k}{v^2 d^2}$. So unless I am missing something, there is no way for us to characterize whether this term should be positive or negative, because we don't know how the product $(vd)^2$ compares to the strength of the central force, $k$. If $v$ is very large and $k$ is very small, for example, the interaction will lead to a "fly-by" rather than a bound system. But it could be that or the opposite, and I don't think there's a way to tell from the information given.

Comment: The term $\frac{k}{v^2d^2}$ is always positive since $k$ is a positive constant (as I stated above) and $v^2d^2$ is positive as well.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I see what you mean. I meant to say that I didn't think we can distinguish whether the fraction or greater than or less than 1, which as you have stated in the question, separates the fly-bys and bound system solutions. So, is there a way to assess whether $k > (l^2v^2)$?

Comment: Don't worry, now I know what you meant. I think they expect to solve it for the case $k > (l^2v^2)$. Even though I thought those initial conditions of the impact parameter already defined the type of orbit. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116985/discussion-between-conraddell-and-zhutchens1).